# Background task finished notification syntax

Tags: bash, shell, job-control

Last night, before abandoning my computer for the evening, I started a bunch of compiler jobs so they'd be ready in the morning, using `make -f alpha.mak &>alpha.out &`. When I came back and hit return, I saw the following output:

```
[1]   Done                    make -f alpha.mak &>alpha.out
[2]-  Done                    make -f beta.mak &>beta.out
[3]+  Done                    make -f gamma.mak &>gamma.out
```

My question: What do the `+` and `-` symbols mean in that output?

I'm using bash on RedHat 6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Bash Reference Manual: Job Control](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_78.html#SEC85):

> In output pertaining to jobs (e.g., the output of the jobs command), the current job is always flagged with a `+', and the previous job with a`-'.