# Please explain the output from the jobs command

Tags: process, command, jobs

When I ran `jobs` command I see the following output :

```
[1]  - Suspended                     ./startWebLogic.sh
[2]  + Suspended (signal)            top
```

1. What does -/+ indicate in the second column ?
2. What is the difference between Suspended and Suspended(signal) ?

Comment: See if [Background task finished notification syntax](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7953/background-task-finished-notification-syntax) answers it.

Comment: @manatwork It does anser the first question but not the second one .

Answer (score 7):

From man pages:

> The character '+' identifies the job that would be used as default for
>   the fg or bg utilities; this job can also be specified using the
>   job_id %+ or "%%" . The character '-' identifies the job that would
>   become the default if the current default job were to exit; this job
>   can also be specified using the job_id %-.

Comment: you didn't answer the send question

Comment: Always wondered what the +/- mean.